# Spring two services with same Transaction?

Tags: spring, hibernate, service, transactional

I have created some spring services with @Service and marked them @Transactional. This is working like expected.

Now I have a created a little Helper Service that executes a google maps request. I have removed the @Transaction annotation in believing that the functions in the Service are using the same transaction.

```
@Transactional
@Service("hourService")
public class HourServiceImpl extends HourService {

    private void updateLogbook(Hour hour) {

        Logbook logbook = getLogbook(hour);

        if (logbook != null) {

            try {

                List<String> locations = logbook.getHours().stream().sorted((t1, t2) -> t1.getStartTime().compareTo(t2.getStartTime())).filter(h -> !h.equals(hour)).map(Hour::getClient).map(Client::getAddress).collect(Collectors.toList());
                locations.add(hour.getClient().getAddress());

                String origin = getOrigin();
                Double distance = mapService.getDistance(origin, origin, locations);

                logbook.add(hour);
                logbook.setProtect(true);
                logbook.setDate(hour.getDate());
                logbook.setDistance(distance / 1000.0);
                logbook.setComment(getComment(logbook.getHours()));

                logbookDao.update(logbook);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logbook.remove(hour);
                log.error("Failed to update Logbook Entry!", e);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

And the mapService

```
@Service("mapService")
public class MapServiceImpl extends MapService {

    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public Double getDistance(String origin, String destination, List<String> waypoints) throws Exception {
        return sendDistanceRequest(origin, destination, waypoints.toArray(new String[waypoints.size()]));
    }

    private Double sendDistanceRequest(String origin, String destination, String... waypoints) throws Exception {

        GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey(environment.getRequiredProperty("invoice.maps.key"));
        DirectionsApiRequest request = DirectionsApi.newRequest(context);
        request.mode(TravelMode.DRIVING);

        request.origin(origin);
        request.destination(destination);
        request.waypoints(waypoints);

        try {

            log.info(String.format("Trying to get Distance for %s -> %s -> %s", origin, String.join(" -> ", waypoints), destination));
            DirectionsResult result = request.await();
            if (result.routes.length > 0 && result.routes[0].legs.length > 0) {

                Double distance = 0d;

                for (DirectionsLeg leg : result.routes[0].legs) {
                    distance += leg.distance.inMeters;
                }

                return distance;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to get maps response!", e);
        }

        throw new Exception(String.format("Something wrong with this route ... ORIGIN: %s, VIAS: %s, DEST: %s", origin, String.join("|", waypoints), destination));

    }

}
```

Now my problem is that calling `mapService.getDistance(origin, origin, locations);` gives me a `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ...Logbook`.

Thats explainable because the logbook entity is not saved and hibernate tries to commit the modified Hour entity ... but why there's a commit? It should use the same Transaction!?!?!?

---

Edit 1

My problem is not related to the mapService. The problem is `getOrigin()` is using my `settingDao` to get a setting value. This call commits the current Transaction and uses another one to select the setting value.

So the question is how to use the same or maybe nested?

Comment: You are calling a method private that will not be transactional. So not sure how you are calling that method or the code you post here isn't actual code.

Comment: I am calling `mapService.getDistance(...)` and this function is public?!? All I want is that calling this function does not commit the Transaction from `HourService` because there are some unsaved entities.

Comment: You are calling public NON transactional method from a private method (the method in the `HourServiceImpl` is private). Depending on how that private method is being called there may or may not be a transaction. Also your edit doesn't make it any better as you are adding information on classes for which you don't provide the implementation, nor do you show where that is called).